# How to cast dynamically loaded annotation class to Annotation?

Tags: java, reflection

I want to achieve the following logic:

1. Load an annotation class with `ClassLoader.loadClass( String )`
2. Check if a given `Class` object has that annotation using `Class.isAnnotationPresent(Class<? extends Annotation>)`

However, the return type of `loadClass()` is `Class<?>`, which cannot be used in `isAnnotationPresent()` directly. So, what steps should I take to use the loaded annotation class in `isAnnotationPresent()`?

This seems a simple problem, but I just fail to find an answer from the mighty Google. :-(

In any case, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Class.asSubclass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass%28java.lang.Class%29):

```
Class<? extends Annotation> a = cl.loadClass(...).asSubclass(Annotation.class);
```